# Scale an image ,keeping aspect ratio without being cropped-android app

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I take the photo from gallery and I display it  on another activity in image view . Everything it's fine except when the photo is displayed. I want the photo to be displayed in the exact same size like the image view keeping the aspect ratio and to not be cropped. I tried everything in xml(centerCrop,fitxy...)This is what I'm trying,but its not working.

showPhotoActivity.class:

```
       ImageView showPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       Uri uri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imagePath"));

    if (showPhoto != null) {
        showPhoto.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        showPhoto.setImageURI(uri);
    }
```

file.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.ga.photoeditor.ShowPhotoActivity"
android:background="#93212121">


<com.example.ga.photoeditor.ScaleImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

ScaleImageView.java

```
public ScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public ScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ScaleImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // Call super() so that resolveUri() is called.
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    // If there's no drawable we can just use the result from super.
    if (getDrawable() == null)
        return;

    final int widthSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int heightSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

    int w = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    int h = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    if (w <= 0)
        w = 1;
    if (h <= 0)
        h = 1;

    // Desired aspect ratio of the view's contents (not including padding)
    float desiredAspect = (float) w / (float) h;

    // We are allowed to change the view's width
    boolean resizeWidth = widthSpecMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

    // We are allowed to change the view's height
    boolean resizeHeight = heightSpecMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

    int pleft = getPaddingLeft();
    int pright = getPaddingRight();
    int ptop = getPaddingTop();
    int pbottom = getPaddingBottom();

    // Get the sizes that ImageView decided on.
    int widthSize = getMeasuredWidth();
    int heightSize = getMeasuredHeight();

    if (resizeWidth && !resizeHeight)
    {
        // Resize the width to the height, maintaining aspect ratio.
        int newWidth = (int) (desiredAspect * (heightSize - ptop - pbottom)) + pleft + pright;
        setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, heightSize);
    }
    else if (resizeHeight && !resizeWidth)
    {
        int newHeight = (int) ((widthSize - pleft - pright) / desiredAspect) + ptop + pbottom;
        setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, newHeight);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can simply apply scaleType:"fitCenter" I think in your ImageView

Comment: It doesn't work,I tried :/ but , thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the available attribute, "scaleType?"

```
<com.example.ga.photoeditor.ScaleImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="320dp"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Experiment with inserting:

```
android:scaleType= [center, centerCrop, centerInside, fitCenter, fitEnd, fitStart, fitXY, or matrix]
```

It seems like you're possibly actually trying to change the dimensions of the imageview itself... which is different, so I apologize if I'm missing the mark.

Comment: That's why I said I tried everything (centerCrop is the best,the image keeps aspect ratio and it's displayed in the dimensions of the image view)except matrix .Can you tell me about matrix more ? Thank you .

Comment: Sorry i dont know what matrix does.  So you're wanting to resize *only one dimension* of the image view in order to fit the original aspect ratio of the image, right?  Perhaps if you change the original imageview width and height to "wrap content" and then shrink the images (maintaining aspect ratio) before assigning them to the imageview?